# Meteor with Cordova Offline Application integration

Tags: cordova, meteor

As I understand it, Cordova is basically just a WebView. When the cordova/meteor app initially attempts to start-up and the mobile device is offline the application never loads. Obviously this is because a connection to the server cannot be made.

- What exactly gets built to the device besides the app details(name, icon...), the main corodva webview wrapper and  cordova specific plugins?
- Secondly, are there any simple solutions within cordova, still using JavaScript, to specify some sort of offline behavior when the app cannot connect to the server. (I know about `Meteor.status()` but if the webpage never loads then I cannot get to the client side code)?

Some ideas would be maybe a notification, or webpage instructing that a online connection is needed that is included in the bundled native application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have some basic set of code that resides on the device. If you do not at least have an index.html and some JavaScript inside that to listen for `deviceready`, then you cannot do much at all.

There is a plugin for getting network information https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md but even without this, you are able to get `offline|online` notifications with code like this (assuming you have included jQuery in your local set of files)

```
jQuery(window).on('offline', function (e) {
    // do stuff when going offline
}).on('online', function (e) {
    // do stuff when going back online
});
```

Comment: So jQuery gets packaged within the native application? Meaning that I can use jQuery functionality without any client-server connection? Meteor.status() returns the client status exactly the same at the above jQuery code, but it needs the intial client-server connection to run. What I am confused about is what code actually gets embedded natively with the cordova app?

Comment: Whatever code you include inside your `www` directory will get packaged with the app. If you want jQuery, simply copy it into that directory structure and then make sure to include it in the index.html as a script tag of course.